# REST expand people column

Tags: 2013, rest, people-picker

I have a list with a people column called **AssignedTo**.  I'm making a rest call:

```
.../_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('listname')/Items?$expand=AssignedTo&$select=*,AssignedTo/Title
```

Which is successfully returning the name of the person the item was assigned to. I'm trying to get other user information like email or their user id.

Most tutorials online show how to expand ID and Title (Name) and [from this blog](http://sympmarc.com/2014/01/21/getting-user-information-with-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api/) I found a list of these properties that can be expanded:

- ID
- FirstName
- LastName
- Title
- Department
- SipAddress

And those all work. But I can't find the email and or the login ID. I've tried **$select=AssignedTo/LoginName** and several other variations on that, but they all return that the field is not valid. I was hoping **$select=AssignedTo/*** would expand all the fields, but that doesn't rework either.

Anyone know if the above are the only fields that can be expanded off a people column?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try AssignedTo/EMail....case sensitive.

Available values from a user field ([Source](https://ajaznusrat.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/using-the-sharepoint-user-type-field-people-or-group-in-list-definition/)):

Title

Name

EMail

MobilePhone

SipAddress

Department

JobTitle

FirstName

LastName

WorkPhone

UserName

Office

ID

Modified

Created

ImnName

NameWithPicture

NameWithPictureAndDetails

ContentTypeDisp

Comment: Can you also suggest a source for this information?

Comment: Added the source.  Couldnt find an MSDN article on it unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

On SharePoint Online, to get the login name (account name) from a user field in a list, you need to select the **Name** property:

```
.../_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items(60)?$select=MyUserField/Name&$expand=MyUserField
```

This returns the account name in the format i:0#.f|membership|user@domain.com. You'll need this value if you want to [query the user profile service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_User) for more info on the user.

Comment: does the same applies for SP 2016? or should we query for a different property

Comment: Just checked on an SP2016 build, and it's exactly the same - expand [NameOfUserField] and select [NameOfUserField]/Name.

Answer (score 2):

I believe by using the person type field you are limited to the fields mentioned in the blog you linked.  You can however make a rest call to get a person's UserProfile properties.

[Vardhaman has a great post on what properties you can access and how to do it.](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html)