# Get another user info using PnPJS with SPFx

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp, pnpjs

I want to get a list of items from a SharePoint list, and display them in a specific way in SPFx webpart. I could use PnPJS to get Text and Number fields, but for the Author field, I am only getting the ID.

I'd like to get some other info, like email address, display name, and user image. My code now looks like this:

```
  sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Projects').items.get().then(items => {
           //console.log(items)
        })
```

However I am getting something like this:

[image]

How can I use AuthorId to get more info about that user?

Answer (score 1):

You need to **select** the person field and use **expand** to get more information about the user like below

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle('Projects').items.get().select('PersonField/FirstName,PersonField/LastName,PersonField/EMail').expand('PersonField').then(items => {
           //console.log(items)
})
```

Here are the values you can [expand from the person field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171288/rest-expand-people-column)